# Question about how to obtain the value of f X|Y(x|y)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, random, estimation

In the following example question (from Bertsekas, edition 1), i have one question:

Why the value of fY|X(y|x) is 1/2?

Is it because Y is Y|X is either 0 or 1/6 (50% probability), or because some other reason? The confusion point for me is that Y = X + W. Then, should fY|X（y|x) should be similar to fx(x)?

I have always have difficulty when I come to look at conditional PDFs for they are not as easily (at least from my part) to understand at this point.

[image]

Comment: In its present form the Question lacks a self-contained problem statement, and little if any research on your part is evident.   It is especially obscure what the least squares estimation mentioned in the title is about, i.e. what are we going to estimate and why is the least squares approach of interest?

Comment: If $W\sim U(-1,1)$, what is the distribution of $x+W?$ This distribution is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $X=x$, $Y$ is uniformly distributed in interval $[x-1,x+1]$ of length $2$, so

\begin{equation}
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=
\begin{cases}
1/2, & x-1\leq y\leq x+1\\
0, &otherwise  
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: so, you are saying for a uniform random variable Y for a given X in an interval of length L, the fY|X(y|x) is 1/L in that interval? (I have seen a similar question on page 226 of this book, but I am not sure if I understand correctly)